# multiple JSESSIONID cookie with JSF

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, shiro, jsf-2.2, jsessionid

I have JEE application Wildfly RC1 JEE7  - CDI,EJB, JSF Mojarra 2.2.4 
In my application i use h:outputLink for create links simply without calling bean actions.

like this

```
<h:outputLink styleClass="btn btn-primary" value="#{request.contextPath}/views/product/addproduct.xhtml" >
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" />
    add product
</h:outputLink>
```

After many navigation, Bean actions don't work. In chrome i discover 3 cookies JSESSIONID with different path corresponding to each navigation link

Any idea to handle this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

source of problem not identified but resolved by replacing apache shiro servlet session manager by

```
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
```

Comment: Please can you explain exactly what you did here? Am having multiple jsessionids with wildfly 8.1 final